# How to re-render component after update hash correctly with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that uses `action` and `repository` to request data from rails server and then render it in component, it returns promise, that I've handle and render:

```
const {loadNews} = props;
const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
const [newsState, setNewsState] = useState('active');
const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(1);
```

where `{loadNews}` - function, that imports from parent component; Others are state, where:

`news` - array with news, that map's in different component in render;
`newsState`- news field state (e.g. 'active', or 'past');
`pageNum`- pagination state for adding more news in component;

I'm use he next code for update state:

```
  const locationHashChanged = () => {
    if (window.location.hash === "#state-active") {
      setNewsState('active');
      setPageNum(pageNum);

    }
    else if (window.location.hash == "#state-played") {
      setNewsState('played');
      setPageNum(pageNum);
    }
  }

  window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;

  const changeHash = () => {
    setNews([]);
    setNewsState('active');
    setPageNum(1)
    loadNews({pageNum, newsState});
  };

  const incrementPage = () => {
    setPageNum(pageNum + 1);
    loadNews({pageNum, newsState});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    locationHashChanged();
    loadNews({pageNum, newsState})
      .then((response) => {
        const {data} = response;
        setNews(news.concat(data));
      })
      .catch((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }, [pageNum, newsState]);
```

If I just use `incrementPage` function - it works fine - it just add more `news` with previous array of news and update state. But, I see that state is updated, but array is not.

Expected behaviour - when I click on link in `Header` component (external component), that changes hash in this component ('active' or 'past' fields) and these news should reload with correct fields(`active` or `past`). But now I see no changes. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: setNews([...news.concat(data])); will update the ref and rect will know there is change in state

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS unfortunatelly, it doesn't work